# How to find inserted records in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, mule

I'm trying to insert records from mule ESB to salesforce using create operation.

I got response

```
[[SaveResult  errors='{[0]}' id='0016F00001wIGeaQAG' success='true']]
```

But when I go to enter find record in salesforce couldn't find when I click on Account tab.

Where can I find these inserted records in salesforce?

Comment: Did you check record with its id `0016F00001wIGeaQAG`?

Comment: I'm able to fetch the record by querying same table but  where can i find this record in salesforce?

Comment: `https://ap1.salesforce.com/0016F00001wIGeaQAG` replace instance url with your url

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can view the account using link https://login.salesforce.com/0016F00001wIGeaQAG

If you know your instance ID, replace login in the URL with instance ID.

Answer (score 0):

Login to SandBox and navigate to Developer Console under the username tab. This would open new window with query editor.

You can write SOQL(salesforce obj query lang) and execute to see if the record has been inserted.

The query would look something like this -

SELECT ,  FROM Account where Id = '0016F00001wIGeaQAG'

And Execute.